# Why didn’t Lillian kiss Fiona?

Tags: shrek

OK, so Fiona’s curse goes:

> By night one way,
>   By day another,
>   Until you find true love’s kiss,
>   And then take love’s true form.

True love. True love. So why didn't Queen Lillian kiss Fiona? As *Frozen* and *Maleficent* pointed out, true love doesn't have to be romantic, it can be between family or even friends. Also, King Harold seemed to be more prejudiced against his daughter’s curse and anyway, he was born a frog, whereas Queen Lillian  was born human and loved Fiona enough that she accepted Shrek into the family. So why didn't *she* kiss Fiona?

Comment: Shrek is a Dreamworks property whereas Frozen and Maleficent are Disney. Since they're in two entire different universes with no obvious crossover (aside from parodical ones, obviously) there's no sensible way to answer this question.

Comment: I know, but my question was that, why didn’t Queen Lillian kiss Fiona? That way, the events of the movies would never have happened.

Comment: Because it's only in (recent) **Disney** films that true love's kiss can (apparently) include family members. Shrek isn't a Disney film and hence the same rules don't apply. You might as well ask whether Mushu is related to Toothless

Comment: @Valorum obviously Mushu isn't related to Toothless.  He's related to Smaug! :)

Comment: It is also possible she tried, but that the curse didn't accept it as an answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Your prince is in another castle.

Comment: You may as well ask why Anna didn't go back to Elsa for true love's kiss, instead of running back to Hans.  Answer for both plots: It never occurred to any of the characters that it could work that way, and just "family hugs'n'kisses" may not have qualified as a true love rather than the more dramatic sacrifices that were required.  Curses would be awfully easy to beat otherwise, dontcha think?

Comment: 2 answer your point about Anna going back 2 Elsa for true love’s kiss, she is naive and believes in the stereotypical fairy tale standards of “curse put on you, so romantic true love has to kiss you.” Plus the trolls saying what they said mightn’t have helped matters.

Answer (score 5):

*Frozen* and *Maleficent* are in different universes by a different studio, so their canon has no bearing on *Shrek*.

There is nothing within the *Shrek* universe to indicate that "true love" can be anything other than romantic love. Queen Lillian may have well kissed Fiona (and what mother doesn't kiss her daughter goodnight), but it will not have worked.

---

Alternatively, Queen Lillian may not have truly loved her cursed daughter.

Comment: Well, that’s being prejudiced against different kinds of true love. True love can lie between friends and family, as I pointed out in my original question.

Comment: What part of "there is nothing within the _Shrek_ universe to indicate that 'true love' can be anything other than romantic love" is still unclear?